# Cannot find shared object file even though it's in library path

Tags: dynamic-linking, ld

I am trying to install plexmediaplayer from source. This involves compiling libmpv.so.1 which I've done and installed under /usr/local/lib

When I run plexmediaplayer, I get the following error:

```
$ plexmediaplayer 
plexmediaplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libmpv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ldconfig finds the library correctly:

```
$ ldconfig -v | grep libmpv
libmpv.so.1 -> libmpv.so.1.24.0
```

ldd on the plexmiediaplayer binary shows libmpv:

```
$ ldd plexmediaplayer | grep libmpv
libmpv.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1 (0x00007f2fe4f33000)
```

which is a symlink:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb  9 20:37 /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1 -> libmpv.so.1.24.0
```

both the shared object and executable are compiled for x86_64 and readable by the non-root user trying to run plexmediaplayer:

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0
/usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=855d9cbf952c76e3c0c1c1a162c4c94ea5a12b91, not stripped
$ file /usr/local/bin/plexmediaplayer 
/usr/local/bin/plexmediaplayer: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dc92ac026c5ac7bc3e5554a591321de81a3f4576, not stripped
```

These both match my machine arch:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running strace on plexmediaplayer gives the following:

```
$ strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file plexmediaplayer
open("/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64//lib/tls/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64//lib/tls/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64//lib/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64//lib/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Which includes:

```
open("/usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

but the permissions on the file through the symlink are:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27872856 Mar 22 22:17 /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0
```

Any ideas why this can't be found by my binary?

EDIT: I wiped all libmpv under `/usr/local/lib` and plexmediaplayer under `/usr/local/bin`, and removed by source directory, then reinstalled side-by-side in a VM. The build in the VM worked, the one on my host machine did not. I also hashed ld on both machines, and (unsurprisingly) they match.

Comment: Is there an error or something from plexmediaplayer when you start it? If so, what is that?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include it. I've added the error to the top of my question.

Comment: Okay can you `strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file plexmediaplayer` and then `grep libmpv.so.1 lotsalogs.*` so we can see what exactly it's failing on?

Comment: @thrig updated with strace output.

Comment: Can you as a not-root user read the file, e.g. `file /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0` ?

Comment: Yes. As non-root user (same one that was trying to run plexmediaplayer):
file /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0
/usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.1.24.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=855d9cbf952c76e3c0c1c1a162c4c94ea5a12b91, not stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I (badly?) configured apparmor for plexmediaplayer months ago, which caused the problem upon updating and recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by running `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libmpv*.so /usr/lib32`

`ldd plexmediaplayer` showed the same and despite the libs being there, they weren't working.